# insert a drop down list in element td after click and then post selected value to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to execute following steps: -

1. Insert a *drop down list* in a TD element, *after* clicking over
   it.
2. Select some value from *drop down list*.
3. After selection, **POST** such selected value to **some.php** file.
4. some.php file will update **somedb** database.
5. display value in TD element from **somedb** database.

For being specific, I know how to execute step 4 and step 5?

I need help in Step 1 to 3, for which I code [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCdnRjZt5DwV2tFYnE4a25jaG8/view?usp=sharing).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Datalist Element Demo
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(function(){
            $('td').click(function(){
              // this.textContent = 'Sukumar';
              var $this = $(this);
              var $input = $('<input>', {
                value: $this.text(),
                type: 'text',
                blur: function() {
                  $this.text(this.value);
                }
                ,
                keyup: function(e) {
                  if (e.which === 13) $input.blur();
                }
              }
                            ).appendTo( $this.empty() ).focus();
            }
                         );
          }
           );
        </script>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
          <h1>Drop Down Demo
          </h1>
          <table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name
                </th>
                <th>A
                </th>
                <th>B
                </th>
                <th>C
                </th>
                <th>D
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Sukumar
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                </td>
                <td>No
                </td>
                <td>No
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="Sukumar 's datalist">
          <datalist id="json-datalist">
          </datalist>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1 - You can add an eventListener to the `td` you want or follow any dorpdown menu tutorial (like: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp ). 2- add an eventListener for the `<li>`s of the dropdown menu to execute a function onclick (or simply add the `onclick` attribute to their HTML) that will update a variable with the value of the clicked `li` (say, for the first `li`, that variable will be `1`). 3- use AJAX or a hack with a form element (CSS `display:none`) to submit the data. 4 and 5 you said you already know

Comment: I thank for your help, I am looking to use jquery post method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ as given following on this page:-

Alert the results from requesting test.php with an additional payload of data (HTML or XML, depending on what was returned).


$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });

but, instead of alert I wish to display data from somedb database.